# Pulse noisy simulation using Fake Jakarta (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm trying to use FakeJakarta from Qiskit to run the PulseObj for noisy simulation but I get error when I run the pulseobj in the noisy backend. It would be great if someone can provide an example to execute the pulseobj using Fake backend in Qiskit.

```
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit import IBMQ, transpile
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeJakarta
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from numpy import pi

device_backend = FakeJakarta()
simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
sim_jakarta = AerSimulator.from_backend(device_backend)
backend = 'ibmq_jakarta'
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
devise = provider.get_backend(backend)
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(devise)
coupling_map = devise.configuration().coupling_map
basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates


qreg_cin = QuantumRegister(1, 'cin')
qreg_a = QuantumRegister(1, 'a')
qreg_b = QuantumRegister(1, 'b')
qreg_cout = QuantumRegister(1, 'cout')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
original_circ = QuantumCircuit(qreg_cin, qreg_a, qreg_b, qreg_cout, creg_c)

# set input states
original_circ.x(qreg_a[0])
original_circ.x(qreg_b[0])
original_circ.cx(qreg_a[0], qreg_b[0])
original_circ.cx(qreg_a[0], qreg_cin[0])
original_circ.ccx(qreg_cin[0], qreg_b[0], qreg_a[0])
original_circ.cx(qreg_a[0], qreg_cout[0])
original_circ.ccx(qreg_cin[0], qreg_b[0], qreg_a[0])
original_circ.cx(qreg_a[0], qreg_cin[0])
original_circ.cx(qreg_cin[0], qreg_b[0])
original_circ.measure(qreg_b[0], creg_c[0])
original_circ.measure(qreg_cout[0], creg_c[1])
original_circ.draw(output='mpl',idle_wires=False, fold=-1)
trans_circ = transpile(original_circ,backend=devise,optimization_level = 3)
trans_circ_gate =trans_circ
trans_circ.draw(output='mpl',idle_wires=False, fold=-1)
sched_circ = schedule(trans_circ,backend=devise)
sched_circ.instructions
sched_circ.draw()
result = sim_jakarta.run(sched_circ).result()
```

Traceback:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6ae2d75da147> in <module>
----> 1 result = sim_jakarta.run(sched_circ).result()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/utils/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     26             if kwargs:
     27                 _rename_kwargs(func.__name__, kwargs, kwarg_map, category)
---> 28             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     29 
     30         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_aer/backends/aerbackend.py in run(self, circuits, validate, parameter_binds, **run_options)
    185             qobj = self._assemble(circuits, **run_options)
    186         else:
--> 187             qobj = self._assemble(circuits, parameter_binds=parameter_binds, **run_options)
    188 
    189         # Optional validation

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_aer/backends/aerbackend.py in _assemble(self, circuits, parameter_binds, **run_options)
    398                         qobj = qobj_tmp
    399             else:
--> 400                 qobj = assemble(circuits, backend=self)
    401 
    402             # Add optypes to qobj

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/assembler.py in assemble(experiments, backend, qobj_id, qobj_header, shots, memory, max_credits, seed_simulator, qubit_lo_freq, meas_lo_freq, qubit_lo_range, meas_lo_range, schedule_los, meas_level, meas_return, meas_map, memory_slot_size, rep_time, rep_delay, parameter_binds, parametric_pulses, init_qubits, **run_config)
    227         end_time = time()
    228         _log_assembly_time(start_time, end_time)
--> 229         return assemble_schedules(
    230             schedules=experiments, qobj_id=qobj_id, qobj_header=qobj_header, run_config=run_config
    231         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/assembler/assemble_schedules.py in assemble_schedules(schedules, qobj_id, qobj_header, run_config)
     53     """
     54     if not hasattr(run_config, "qubit_lo_freq"):
---> 55         raise QiskitError("qubit_lo_freq must be supplied.")
     56     if not hasattr(run_config, "meas_lo_freq"):
     57         raise QiskitError("meas_lo_freq must be supplied.")

QiskitError: 'qubit_lo_freq must be supplied.'
```
````